# Flip a seconday display horizontally - and make it permanent

Tags: display, xrandr

I have flipped a secondary display horizontally, since it is going to be used on a teleprompter.
Used `xrandr -x` to achieve this.

Now, I would like to store this, so next time I boot up / reboot, this setting is applied.

Using Ubuntu 20.10.